# Intersection between a natural logarithmic function and its inverse function

Tags: logarithms, inverse-function

I've been stuck on this math problem for a while and it involves solving the intersections between a natural log and its inverse function.

The natural log function is: $\ln(x+2)+3$

The inverse function is: $e^{x-3}-2$

I understand that they reflect on the $y=x$ line, but when I write them down as: $\ln(x+2)+3 = e^{x-3}-2$, I can't go any further than $\ln(x+2)+5 = e^{x-3}$.

So I was wondering if there is anyway I can solve this without putting it into the graphics calculator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since the function is increasing, you may change the equation to $e^{x-3}-2=x$ or $\ln(x+2)+3=x$. I have seen no elementary way of solving this equation without numerical method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We better subtract both sides with $\ln(x+2)+5$,
$$F(x)=\ln(x+2)-e^{x-3}+5$$
this kind of function is called a transcendental function, and we often use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#:%7E:text=Newton%27s%20method%20is%20a%20powerful,roughly%20doubles)
to find it's root, If you want high accuracy, it can be really hard to solve by hand, almost impossible. But if you only need accuracy at, say 2 decimal places, Newton's method works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Newton's Method may be a bit beyond me at the moment, but I'll be sure to read it into it. It may not be too far into the future when I have to learn it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you want to find the positive zero of function
$$f(x)=\log(x+2)-e^{x-3}+5$$ the solution should be close to $x=5$ since $e^2 \sim 7.4$ and $\log(7) \sim 2$.

Let $x=t+5$ and make a series expansion around $t=0$; limited to two terms, this gives
$$f(t)=\log (t+7)-e^{t+2}+5=\left(5-e^2+\log (7)\right)+\left(\frac{1}{7}-e^2\right)
   t-\left(\frac{1}{98}+\frac{e^2}{2}\right)
   t^2+O\left(t^3\right)$$

Using a series reversion
$$t=\frac{7 \left(\log (7)-e^2+5\right)}{7 e^2-1}+\frac{7 (1+49e^2) \left(\log (7)-e^2+5\right)^2}{(7 e^2-1)^3}+\cdots=-0.0630678$$

So, as an *approximation*, $x=4.93692$ while the "exact" solution (given by Newton method) is $x=4.93685$.

For sure, we could do much better with one more term; the same process would lead to $x=4.936851$ to be compared the exact $4.936847$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I haven't actually learnt about series reversion yet, so I can't quite understand the working, but I'll be sure to look into it.